# How can I inject a touch event Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I want to inject a touch event *Android Studio* during app running at background.
After searching it, I found a couple of solutions but all of them need *root* rights.
For my private use, I am trying to make a remote control app (like *TeamViewer Quicksupport*) that streams to my video streaming server ***`RTMP&RTSP`*** and I need to inject tap (via touching) and input (via typing).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45414862/115145

Comment: I read but its old post, maybe there is somthing news :)